# Apple BROKE importing "iTunes Library.xml", now ONLY imports playlists - not everything

Tags: itunes

As the title says the old "import 'iTunes Library.xml' and migrate everything" trick is no longer working as of iTunes 12.5.5.9 at least.

Does anyone know a workaround or alternate technique for achieving the old behavior? I was in the middle of merging almost a DOZEN older iTunes libraries when I noticed the trick had stopped working!

Comment: What trick exactly and what does it do now

Comment: @Mark - Formerly if you went to "File > Library > Import Playlist" and imported the file created by telling a different iTunes library (say from an old computer) to "File > Library > Export Library", the new library would import EVERYTHING (playlists, songs, ratings, play counts, all of it) and now the same command sequence ONLY imports the Playlists AND NOTHING ELSE!

Comment: Sounds like something you ought to be reporting to https://bugreport.apple.com